# Test-Automation using MetaProgramming

Tags: testing, metaprogramming

i want to learn  test automation using meta programming.i googled it could not find any thing.can anybody suggest me some resources where can i get info about "how  to use Meta Programming for making test automation easy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a broad topic and not a lot has been written about it, because of the "dark corners" of metaprogramming.

**What do you mean by "metaprogramming"?**

As background, I consider metaprogramming to be any activity in which a tool (which we call a "metaprogramming tool") is used to inspect or modify the application software to achieve some effect.

Many people consider "reflection" to be a kind of metaprogramming; other consider (C++-style) templates to be metaprogramming; some suggest aspect-oriented programming.

I sort of agree but think these are weak versions of what you want, because each has severe limits on what it can see or do to source code.  What you really want is a metaprogramming tool that has access to *everything* in your source program (yes, comments too!)  Such tools are called [Program Transformation Systems (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation); they work by parsing the source code and operating on the parsed representation of the program.  (I happen to build one of these, see my bio).  PTSes can then analyze the code accurate, and/or make *reliable* changes to the code and regenerate valid source with the changes.   PS: a PTS can implement all those other metaprogramming techniques as special cases, so it is strictly more general.

**Where can you use metaprogramming for testing?**

There are at least 2 areas in which metaprogramming might play a role:

1) Collection of information from tests
2) Generation of tests
3) Avoidance of tests

**Collection.**

Collection of test results depends on the nature of tests.  Many tests are focused on "is this white/black box functioning correctly"?  Assuming the tests are written somehow, they have to have access to the box under test, 
be able to invoke that box in a realistic ways, determine if the result is correct, and often tabulate the results to that post-testing quality assessments can be made.

Access is the first problem.  The black box to be tested may not be easily accessible to a testing framework:  driven by a UI event, in a non-public routine, buried deep inside another function where it hard to get at.
You may need metaprogramming to "temporarily" modify the program to provide access to the box that needs testing (e.g., change a Private method to Public so it can be called from outside).   Such changes exist only for the duration of the test project; you throw the modified program away because nobody wants it for anything but the test results.  Yes, you have to ensure that the code transformations applied to make things visible don't change the program functionality.

The second problem is exercising the targeted black box in a realistic environment.  Each code module runs in a world in which it assumes data and the environment are "properly" configured.  The test program can set up that world explicitly by making calls on lots of the program elements or using its own custom code; this is usually the bulk of a test routine, and this code is hard to write and fragile (the application under test keeps changing; so do its assumptions about the world).   One might use metaprogramming to instrument the application to *collect* the environment under which a test might need to run, thus avoiding the problem of writing all the setup code.

Finally, one might want to record more than just "test failed/passed".  Often it is useful to know exactly what code got tested ("test coverage").  One can instrument the application to collect what-got-executed data; here's how to do it for code blocks: http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/TestCoverage.pdf using a PTS.    More sophisticated instrumentation might be used to capture information about which *paths* through the code have been executed.  Uncovered code, and/or uncovered paths, show where tests have not been applied and you arguably know nothing about what the program does, let alone whether it is buggy in a straightforward way.

**Generation of tests**

Someone/thing has to *produce* tests; we've already discussed how to produce the set-up-the-environment part.  What about the functional part?
Under the assumption that the program has been debugged (e.g, already tested by hand and fixed), one could use metaprogramming to instrument the code to capture the *results* of execution of a black box (e.g., instance execution post-conditions).   By exercising the program, one can then produce (by definition) "correctly produces" results which can be transformed into a test.  In this way, one might construct a huge variety of *regression* tests for an existing program; these will be valuable in verifying the further enhancements to the program don't break most of its functionality.

Often a function has qualitatively different behaviors on different ranges of input (e.g., for x<10, produced x+1, else produces x*x).  Ideally one would like to provide a test for each qualitively different results (e.g, x<10, x>=10) which means one would like to partition the input ranges.  Metaprogrammning can help here, too, by enumerating all (partial) paths through module, and providing the predicate that controls each path.
The separate predicates each represent the input space partition of interest.

**Avoidance of Tests**

One only tests code one does not trust (surely you aren't testing the JDK?) Any code consructed by a reliable method doesn't *need* tests (the JDK was constructed this way, or at least Oracle is happy to have you beleive it).

Metaprogramming can be used to automatically *generate* code from specifications or DSLs, in relaible ways.   Such generated code is correct-by-construction (we can argue about what degree of rigour), and doesn't need tests.   You might need to test that DSL expression achieves the functionaly you desired, but you don't have to worry about whether the generated code is right.